# SQL Server database special query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table in a SQL Server database with three columns (`SerialNo`, `UserName`, `Password`). Now, I can read any data using the SQL command select.

But is there a way to count the column number of the database table? In my case, I want to return the column number of the column 'Password' which is 3.

Finally Succeed. Posted the full answer. Thanks everyone of this awesome community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [`information_schema.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select *
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = ? and table_schema = ?;
```

If you want the position of `'password'` then use:

```
select ordinal_position
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name = ? and table_schema = ? and
      column_name = 'password';
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, sure - you can inspect the `sys.columns` catalog view and get the SQL Server internal `column_id` for any column with this code:

```
SELECT
    ColumnName = c.name,
    ColumnIndex = c.column_id
FROM
    sys.columns c
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.--Your-Table-Name-Here--')
ORDER BY
    c.column_id
```

But what do you want to do with this??

Comment: column_id might not reflect the actual ordinal position if columns are dropped. Your question about why is a good one.

Comment: @DanGuzman: exactly - plus even if you know the `column_id` - what good does that really do you? If you have a `SELECT`, the index of a column depends on the column list - not the `column_id` in the catalog views.....

Comment: I want to create a two dimensional array to fill the database table dynamically. @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT
    sys.columns.column_id
FROM
    sys.columns
WHERE
    sys.columns.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.**users**') 
    AND 
    sys.columns.name = '**password**'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to test the code **Gordon Linoff** suggested. Here is the test code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace TestingColumnIDPullling
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            int id;
            con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.Setting);
            con.Open();
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter User Id");
           // id = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string query = "select ordinal_position from information_schema.columns c where table_name = 'Test' and table_schema = 'dbo' and column_name = 'Password'";
            reader = new SqlCommand(query, con).ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetInt32(0));
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    }
}
```